# Mercurial; Possible to list the # of commits a certain user has made?

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like:

```
hg log --user whoever@example.com | grep --count "user"   # UNIX or Windows with grep installed.
hg log --user whoever@example.com | find /c "user"   # Windows.
```

If your grep doesn't have a `--count` option, it may well have an equivalent `-c` option.

Comment: better to use `log -q |wc -l`

Answer (score 5):

I would use the [`churn` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChurnExtension) which generates nice histograms for this. It looks like this for one of my repositories:

```
$ hg churn --changesets
mg@daimi.au.dk               1034 ******************************************
mkeller@cs.au.dk              132 *****
mg@cs.au.dk                   102 ****
janus.nielsen@alexandra.dk     87 ****
mk@daimi.au.dk                 32 *
stm@daimi.au.dk                15 *
mas@daimi.au.dk                13 *
tpj@cs.au.dk                   10 
tomas@daimi.au.dk               6 
tordr@item.ntnu.no              5 
ivan@cs.au.dk                   1 
Marc X. Makkes                  1
```